# how to get same result without for loop in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am looking for another way to achieve the same result because the for statement is too slow.

I have the following data frame.

```
'data.frame':   50000 obs. of  2 variables:
$ user_id: chr  "user1@test.com" "user2@test.com" ......
$ result : logi  NA NA ......
```

Function f takes a user ID and returns a specific result.

```
f <- function(user_id){
 ......
 return(json_result)
}
```

The result I want is as follows.

```
'data.frame':   50000 obs. of  2 variables:
$ user_id: chr  "user1@test.com" "user2@test.com" ......
$ result : chr  "{....}" "{....}" ......
```

I am running a loop like the code below, but the speed is too slow.

```
for (t in df$user_id) {
 print(t)
 df$result[df$user_id==t] <- f(t) 
}
```

It takes about 3 seconds per user, and 3*50000 seconds to get a total of 50,000 users.

Is there any other way to get results faster?

Comment: By using `df$result[df$user_id==t] <- f(t)` wouldn't the same value be repeated in each row of `user_id` ? Shouldn't you have only one row per `user_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `lapply` function:

```
df$result <- lapply(df$user_id, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use purrr's map functions.

```
library(tidyverse)
purrr::map(df$user_id, f)
```

This will output a list where each element is the output of the function call. Depending on the output of your function, you could use a `map` variant to output a vector of some type. You can read about this in the docs: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html